# Why the image of a square under specific linear mapping is different if we define the square in two different ways?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let E1= (1,0) and E2=(0,1) vectors in a plane then if the image of E1 and E2 under a linear map L is:

L(E1) = (1,1) and L(E2)= (-1,2) then the mapping of the square with corns at: (0,0) ; (1,0); (0,1) and (1,1) will form a parallelogram. I proved this statement saying that the square is a set S of element whose are linear combinations of (1,0_  and (0,1) with coefficients of linear combinations greater than 0 and smaller than 1. But trying to proof doing the square to be the set

S = {(x∈R² : x = a(0,0) + b(0,1) + c(1,0) + d(1,1) whe a,b,c,d≥0 and a+b+c+d=1 }

but the image of S under F in this way lead us to:

F(S) = {y∈R²: y = [b-d] (1,1) + [c+d] (0,3) with a+b+c+d=1 and a,b,c,d≥0 }

how can i show that F(S) is a parallelogram? Or can someone please show me where i am going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: If $y \in R^2$, then how does $y=b-d+c+d$? The left side is a vector while the right side is a scalar.

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong, the brackets did not appear i will edit this, thank you.

Comment: You've calculated the transformation wrongly.

Comment: calculated many times and all times i get this results, i will try again tomorrow maybe i am  repeating the mistake, but if you know the right calculation it would be very good, thank you

Comment: We have $$T\Big(b(0,1)\Big) = b(-1,2)\\ T\Big(c(1,0)\Big) = c(1,1)$$ and $$T\Big(d(1,1)\Big) = T\Big(d(1,0) + d(0,1)\Big) = d(1,1)+d(-1,2)=d(0,3)$$ Since $b(-1,2)=b(0,3)-b(1,1)$, the end result should be $[c-b](1,1)+[b+d](0,3)$.